# Sencha ExtJs TextField KeyDown Event in FireFox

Tags: javascript, firefox, extjs, keydown, sencha-architect

So I have the following code that detects where the key that was pressed is a number, space or delete key. If not it stops the key from being entered into the textfield. It works perfectly in Chrome and IE. When I run it in FireFox I get the following error: returnValue is undefined in the following statement: e.event.returnValue = false;

Here is the code:

```
keydown:function( sender, e, eOpts )
                    { 
                        if (!isNumberKey(e))
                        {
                            e.event.returnValue = false;
                        }
                    }
```

The Function that does the work:

```
function isNumberKey(e)
{
//Local Varaible Declaration
var returnValue = false;

if (e.keyCode >= 96 && e.keyCode <= 105)
{
    returnValue = true;
}
else if (e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57)
{
    returnValue = true;
}
else if (e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46)
{
    returnValue = true;
}

return returnValue;
```

}

I looked in the debugger in the firefox and found that returnValue really is not there. What do I use instead? I am sure there must be a way to accomplish this in FireFox.

Thanks,

Josh

Answer (score 3):

It took me like 4 hours but here is the solution. Hope this helps:

```
keydown:function( sender, e, eOpts )
                        { 
                            if (!isNumberKey(e))
                            {
                                if (Ext.browser.is.Firefox) 
                                {
                                    e.event.preventDefault();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    e.event.returnValue = false;
                                }
                            }
                        }
```